# Does application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: wake the app from suspended state for non-silent notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Apple's documentation of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application contains the following sentence:

> In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state **when a remote notification arrives**.

(emphasis mine)

The above seems to imply that: **without user tapping the notification banner or tapping the app icon from home screen**, as long as the remote notifications background mode is enabled, the system will launch the app or put it in background state as long as a remote notification arrives, **regardless of whether it is silent or not**.

However, from personal experiments, it seems to be that the system might only launch the app or put it in background state **when the remote notification is silent**.

Did I read the above documentation wrongly? Or could it be an issue with my personal experiments?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is understanding what "arrives" means. Here it means arrives *at the app*. A non silent push notification that the user ignores never arrives at the app, so the app is not awakened. To put it another way: the whole point of a silent push notification is its ability to arrive at the app without user intervention.

Comment: Going with this interpretation for "tapping on the non-silent push notification == arrives", I don't think the quoted sentence is true either, because it implies that the system will put the app to background **after** the user taps on the non-silent push notification. If the user taps on the push notification, the app will enter the active state, instead of the background state.

Comment: Yeah, I'm certainly not going to defend their docs; personally I never believe what they say. You're right to test and you're right to be skeptical. I'm just trying to help imagine what they might have been thinking when they wrote that rather nontechnical description.